# What's the syntax to compile these functions, whose arguments are nested lists?

Tags: compile

In some case the Compile's syntax is quite straightforward. Es. for rank 1  e rank 2 tensors:

```
Quiet[Remove[cf]];
cf = Compile[
   {{x, _Real, 1}}
   , Total[x]
   ];
```

and

```
Quiet[Remove[cf]];
cf = Compile[
   {{x, _Real, 2}}
   , Inverse[x] (*Inverse isn't compileable: here is used merely as signpost*)

   ];
```

Or, even,

```
Quiet[Remove[cf]];
cf = Compile[
   {{x, _Real, 2}, {y, _Real, 2}}
   , Det[x] + Det[y] (*Det isn't compileable: here is used merely as signpost*)
   ];
cf[matrixA, matrixB]
```

But what if the arguments are intricated ? What is the syntax needed ?

A workaround to circumvent this question was proposed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39360/can-i-return-lists-with-different-dimensions-from-a-compiled-function) : *Not the most elegant but could you flatten and join and then "unflatten" and separate afterwards ?*

Please, can you give examples for a function having as argument (all atomic expression are understood Real):

- a matrix of lists
- a matrix of matrices
- a matrix whose element are {x_Real , a matrix }
- a matrix whose element are {x_List , a matrix }
- etc.

**Addendum**

This question has been put on hold, but in IMHO the answer given below (see [Jokeur](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38786/jokeur)), clarifying what is possible and what is not, fully dissolves the doubt.

Comment: I have restricted the question to few cases. Please, can you propose a further edit to avoid the "too broad" problem ?

Comment: Is the argument the only irregular part? I mean, when the argument is passed into the body of `Compile` ,will they still be irregular, or be broken up into regular lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get something out of the way first: `Det` and `Inverse` are not compileable.

OK, to the question: as noted in [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html#119888435) `Compile` can only handle lists of lists that are tensors, which makes your third and fourth examples not suitable for `Compile`.

Your first and second examples are suitable: in the first case you have a rank-3 tensor (`ArrayDepth` is equal to 3), and in the second case you have a rank-4 tensor. So, those will work.

Thus, here is an alternative for your last two cases: the function can take two arguments, one argument being the matrix of the first components, and the other being the last component of your lists.

---

Anyway here is an example asked for by Marco B. If your hypothetical routine takes an argument like

```
{
  {
    {1, HilbertMatrix[2]},
    {2, ConstantArray[1, {2, 2}]}
  },
  {
    {3, Array[Min, {2, 2}]},
    {4, HilbertMatrix[2]}
  }
}
```

consider rewriting the routine so that it takes the arguments `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` and `{{HilbertMatrix[2], ConstantArray[1, {2, 2}]}, {Array[Min, {2, 2}], HilbertMatrix[2]}}` instead. Now the two arguments are admissible tensors for `Compile`, unlike in the previous format. Similarly for the other example.

Comment: Jokeur, Would you consider perhaps adding a code example for the workaround you proposed at the end of your answer? (+1)